# Installing PySCIPOpt via pip doesn't work

Tags: python, windows, scip

I tried installing PySCIPOpt with pip by doing "pip install pyscipopt" using this guideline:
https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.md and looking at diffrent questions with the same problem. I'm running Python 3.8 with Anaconda on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine.

I have sucessfully installed th SCIP Optimization Suite. I do have the folders lib and include and in the folder include there is a file scip\scip.h. And finally I installed  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.

I run the following commands in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
set SCIPOPTDIR=C:\Program Files\SCIPOptSuite 7.0.0
pip install pyscipopt
```

I've also tried diffrent variations like for example:

```
set SCIPOPTDIR="C:\Program Files\SCIPOptSuite 7.0.0"
set PATH=%PATH%;%SCIPOPTDIR%\bin
python -m pip install pyscipopt
```

However I keep getting the following error message.What am I doing wrong?

```
Collecting PySCIPOpt
  Using cached PySCIPOpt-3.1.0.tar.gz (619 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: PySCIPOpt
  Building wheel for PySCIPOpt (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\<>\anaconda3\envs\<>\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\<>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b0tospyz\\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\<>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b0tospyz\\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-qi79u70_'
       cwd: C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b0tospyz\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\
  Complete output (29 lines):
  Using include path <C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b0tospyz\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\src>.
  Using SCIP library <libscip> at <C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b0tospyz\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\lib>.
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\nodesel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
  running build_ext
  building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PySCIPOpt
  Running setup.py clean for PySCIPOpt
Failed to build PySCIPOpt
Installing collected packages: PySCIPOpt
    Running setup.py install for PySCIPOpt ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\<>\anaconda3\envs\<>\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\<>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b0tospyz\\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\<>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b0tospyz\\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-o4qinppn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\<>\anaconda3\envs\<>\Include\PySCIPOpt'
         cwd: C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b0tospyz\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\
    Complete output (29 lines):
    Using include path <C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b0tospyz\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\src>.
    Using SCIP library <libscip> at <C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b0tospyz\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\lib>.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\Multidict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\scip.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\benders.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\benderscut.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\branchrule.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\conshdlr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\event.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\expr.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\heuristic.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\lp.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\nodesel.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\presol.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\pricer.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\propagator.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\relax.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    copying src\pyscipopt\sepa.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pyscipopt
    running build_ext
    building 'pyscipopt.scip' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\<>\anaconda3\envs\<>\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\<>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b0tospyz\\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\<>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b0tospyz\\pyscipopt_5f447b30c7094ccaa5631ff01e4dab0a\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\<>\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-o4qinppn\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\<>\anaconda3\envs\<>\Include\PySCIPOpt' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you installed build tools from that url in the error?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now. The build  tools really seemed to be the problem. I had installed them but not restarted my Computer afterwards.